# How to call and paste data from an addin function?

Tags: excel, vba

If I have an addin gin function called X(A,B) which seems to paste data into whatever is the activesheet, using =X() on the cell.

How can I call this from VBA? Do I have to do anything special because this function is part of an addin?

I just want to be able to set the active sheet and then call X(), is it as trivial as

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

SomeModule.X(Arg1,Arg2)
```

Thanks

EDIT: I have gone to tools -> references and selected the addin, but i do not get anything in the project explorer pane relating to the reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return the value of the function `X(Arg1,Arg2)` from VBA you could try this:

```
Application.Run("X",Arg1,Arg2)
```

For the first argument it is good practice to be as explicit as possible: `"gin.xla!SomeModule.X"`